# EF core many to many relationship inside a generic repository with DTO and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to make a ASP.Net Core WebAPI, with EF Core 2.2, generic repository and automapper. The issue I have is with mapping many to many relationship. I can get the entry from the database just fine, but when I try to add a member to already existing the `UserRights` property of the `User` model is always `null`.

The models I use are as follows:

```cs
    //Contains the information about the User

    public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Password { get; set; }   //stored encrypted

        public virtual IEnumerable<UserRight> UserRights { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string DecryptedPassword
        {
            get { return Decrypt(Password); }
            set { Password = Encrypt(value); }
        }

        private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            return EntityHelper.Decrypt(cipherText);
        }

        private string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            return EntityHelper.Encrypt(clearText);
        }
    }

    // Contains information about the different rights user can have
    public class Right : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public DateTime SetActive { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<UserRight> UserRights { get; set; }
    }

    // Join table
    public class UserRight 
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public int RightId { get; set; }
        public virtual Right Right { get; set; }
    }

    // Base class for the database
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    // Base class for the DTO classes
    public class BaseDomain
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }


    public class UserDto : BaseDomain
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public IList<RightDto> Rights { get; set; }
    }

    public class RightDto : BaseDomain
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime SetActive { get; set; }

        public List<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

The repository and the services:

```cs
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        }

    ...

        public void Update(object id, T entity)
        {
            if (entity != null)
            {
               _unitOfWork.Context.Entry(entitytoUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                var local = _unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>()
                .Local
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
                if (local != null)
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }

                _unitOfWork.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    ...
    }



    public class GenericService<Tv, Te> : IService<Tv, Te> where Tv : BaseDomain
                                                           where Te : BaseEntity
    {

        protected IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public GenericService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public GenericService()
        {
        }
    ...
        public virtual int Update(Tv view)
        {
            _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Te>().Update(view.Id, Mapper.Map<Te>(source: view));
            return _unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Tv> Get(Expression<Func<Te, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var entities = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Te>()
                .Get(predicate: predicate);
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Tv>>(source: entities);
        }
    ...
    }





    public class UserService<Tv, Te> : GenericService<Tv, Te> where Tv : UserDto
                                                              where Te : User
    {

        public UserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork == null)
                _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Tv> Get(Expression<Func<Te, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var entities = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Te>()
                .Get(predicate: predicate);

            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Tv>>(source: entities);
        }
    }
```

The AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DecryptedPassword))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Rights, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.UserRights.Select(y => y.Right).ToList()));

        CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DecryptedPassword, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Password));

        CreateMap<Right, RightDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Users, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.UserRights.Select(y => y.User).ToList()));
        CreateMap<RightDto, Right>();


        CreateMap<RightDto, UserRight>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Right, y => y.MapFrom(z => z))
            .ForMember(x => x.RightId, y => y.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.UserId, y => y.Ignore()); 


        CreateMap<UserDto, UserRight>()
            .ForMember(x => x.User, y => y.MapFrom(z => z))
            .ForMember(x => x.RightId, y => y.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.UserId, y => y.Ignore()); 

        CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
    }
```

I am trying to add a right to the existing user in `Controller`:

```cs
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserService<UserDto, User> _userService;
        private readonly RightService<RightDto, Right> _rightService;

        public UserController(UserService<UserDto, User> userService, RightService<RightDto, Right> rightService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _rightService = rightService;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            var item = _userService.Get(x => x.Id == 1).ToList();

            if (item == null)
            {
                Log.Error("NOT FOUND");
                return NotFound();
            }

            var rights = _rightService.GetAll().ToList();
            item[0].FirstName = "Changed";
            item[0].Rights.Add(rights[4]);
            var test = _userService.Update(item[0]);

            return Ok(item);
        }
```

How can I save/update the `User` and it's `Right`s by passing the Dto and is it possible at all?

Also is this the right direction for EF Core usage?